# Why two computations for distance half way around the world don't agree?

Tags: geodesy

I understand WGS84 models the equator as a circle with radius=GeodesyData["WGS84","SemimajorAxis"]. So I expected the two computations below to be the same. Where is my mistake?

```
Pi*GeodesyData["WGS84","SemimajorAxis"]
(* 2.00375 * 10^7 m *)

UnitConvert@GeoDistance[GeoPosition@{0,0},GeoPosition@{0,180}]
(* 2.00039 * 10^7 m *)
```

Comment: From your comment to Michael's answer I understand your original question (“Why two computations for distance half way around the equator don't agree?”) implied a misunderstanding of your computation proper. Editing your question might help others with a similar problem.

Comment: I edited the Title.

Comment: [@Ted Ersek](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/460/ted-ersek) Looks good!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The shortest (geodesic) distance is not around the equator.  Try

```
UnitConvert@ GeoDistance[
 {GeoPosition@{0, 0}, GeoPosition@{0, 90}, GeoPosition@{0, 180}}]
(*  Quantity[2.00375*10^7, "Meters"]  *)
```

and

```
UnitConvert@ GeoDistance[
 {GeoPosition@{0, 0}, GeoPosition@{90, 0}, GeoPosition@{0, 180}}]
(*  Quantity[2.00039*10^7, "Meters"]  *)
```

Comment: Right, the shortest path crosses the North or South pole. We get half the perimeter around the equator using     UnitConvert@
 GeoDistance[{GeoPosition@{0, 0}, GeoPosition@{0, 90}, 
   GeoPosition@{0, 180}}]
(* 2.00375 * 10^7 m *)